# No sound in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - help requested

Tags: sound

I am very new to Ubuntu. Installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS yesterday with the help of documentation available on Ubuntu home page. Please note I am a beginner hence not much familiar with terminals/commands etc. I am keen to learn Ubuntu hence installed.

Installation was via USB method and successful, but there was no sound after that. My windows plays sound hence I do not suspect my soundcard. My PC is bit old - it is Toshiba Equium P200.

I came to know from web that there is a lot no audio issues reported against this version of Ubuntu, but I couldnt find a method by which I can correct this. At this moment I am unable to understand what level of logs I need to produce as an evidence or to help issue investigation since my knowledge is limited. Can some one please extend your helping hands ?

Thanks

Comment: open terminal, and run sudo apt install inxi, and then run inxi -SMA and edit your question and post the output of the command

Answer (score 0):

First, check your settings and see what the audio output (sink) and input (source) are set to.  Open the Settings and click on the Sound tab to do this.  In my case, it showed both to be USB audio and since I do not have USB audio devices connected, I got no sound.

Then open a terminal window and enter the command below.  Your results will, of course, be different.

```
$ pactl list short sinks
1   alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock_1__sink module-alsa-card.c  s24le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock__sink   module-alsa-card.c  s24le 2ch 48000Hz   IDLE
3   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

This tells me that the sink (output device) that I want is the 3rd one in the list.  Make note of the text string for the device you want.  For me it is 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo'.

Similarly run:

```
$ pactl list short sources
1   alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock_1__sink.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s24le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock__sink.monitor   module-alsa-card.c  s24le 2ch 48000Hz   RUNNING
3   alsa_input.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock__source  module-alsa-card.c  s24le 2ch 48000Hz   RUNNING
4   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
5   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

The source I want is 'alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo'.

Then enter the following commands (using your desired sink and source of course):

```
$ pactl set-default-sink 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo'
$ pactl set-default-source 'alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo'
```

Check the Settings > Sound.  The settings should be correct, and if you used the right devices your audio should work.

Once you know that it's right, just edit your .profile file and add these two pactl commands to that file.